# Log files of Oracle Concurrent Requests

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apps

I know that a log file and an out file is generated for each concurrent request and stored physically as .log and .out files. But is there a possibility that the log or output is stored in a table where we can view?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with Oracle Apps.

But you can build something alike yourselves easily with some cooperation of the DBA. (Maybe there is even a FND_xxx that does it, but I don't have Apps available now and it is some years ago, so I am rusty).

All concurrent requests log into the same directory.

Create an Oracle directory pointing to that one.

Then use for instance a pipelined function to access the contents as if it is a table.

Comment: Why not suggest an external table?  Querying files using SQL is their core Use Case.

Comment: Is also possible depending on rdbms version. Note that the files have no structure itself, just ascii files so you need to choose crlf or so as separator.

Comment: The OP clearly specifies the database version (11g).  And I'm not sure how pipelined functions solve the problem of structure better than external tables.

Comment: Ah, didnt see on the iphone, on 11g it will run. There may be many hundreds of thousands files (hmm, not always, but often thousands). External tables require fixed location but correct when it is possible without ddl to create one new for every file easily (avoid dynamic ddl and some dd pollution but that is considerably less with 11g since it tries to reuse id's in dd). Pipelined table function allows pl/sql, returning few kb per line, and can easily link without ddl to another file. We use them successfully in our own scheduling solution for similar scenarios and it runs on many versions

Comment: Easing maintenance when the software is or becomes a standard software package. Therefore i would prefer them. On oracle7 and 8 we used even horror external daemons for accessing files using db pipes, but they can be sensitive to crashes and not being freed up and blocking shutdown abort (yes, it can be blocked someyimed). Sometimes only startup force could reanimate oracle well and reliably. Probably pipes are now more stable, but utlfile seems to gave been better always.